# Weird image injection when using YUI grid

Tags: javascript, css, image, code-injection, yui-grids

I was trying to use YUI grid and i noticed something weird coming up on my webpage:

```
<img id="fvdkoff-target-image" style="border: medium none ; margin: 0px; position: relative; visibility: visible; color: transparent; z-index: 2147483647; left: 424px; top: 274px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
```

I was wondering if anyone faced this issue?

the above weird image injection kindda breaks my website's design.

Can anyone help?

Take a look at here: http://140.119.19.139/media_user/layout14/sample.html

by the way, the weird code injected doesnt show up in the source code. however, if you try to debug the page using FireBug and click on the white space below the footer, it will clearly show the injected code.

best.

Comment: What do you mean, "breaks"?  What do you mean by "image injection"? Is the problem possibly that you're using IE, which doesn't support data URLs like that?

Comment: By "breaks" I mean that that particular piece of code is filling up the bottom of my web design, beneath the footer. My web design's entire background is blue in color, but the above code is filling my design up in white.

If I do not use YUI, than this problem does not occur.

I've checked using Firebug and it revealed to be an image, as shown by the code above.

I've tested on different browsers (Chrome, IE8, Firefox ) and the same thing happens.

Comment: Do you have a live site we can look at to see the issue?

Comment: Well what exactly are you doing with YUI to introduce this thing?  Without seeing more of your page and your Javascript, it's hard to say. I don't use YUI so maybe somebody who does would instantly recognize that markup.

Comment: here it is: http://140.119.19.139/media_user/layout14/sample.html

The white that is created under the footer is caused by the code I have pasted in this thread.

Please help`~~~

Comment: by the way, the weird code injected doesnt show up in the source code. however, if you try to debug the page using FireBug and click on the white space below the footer, it will clearly show the injected code.

Comment: nope. cant reproduce. :(

Comment: also can you also post what other extension you have installed ?

Comment: and also which editor are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

When I inspect the page with Firebug I don't get the image. I do see the white space. Its there because reset-fonts-grid.css is setting the background of the `html` element to white.

If you select the `html` element in Firebug and toggle off the `background` rule in the style inspector your background behaves as expected.

As for the image, I don't know what it is, why you see it and I don't, or where it came from, but google searches on "fvdkf image" show it popping up all over the place.

As a sidenote, this post has been live for 40 minutes and its already the #4 google result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be some sort of script injection, but the 'src' attribute is an encoded string that renders as a .png file - like a little word bubble icon. try copying the value and pasting it into the address bar of your browser to take a look. Does that help?